# How to add new rows to an Apache Flink Table

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-batch

Is it possible to add a new record/row to a flink table? For example i have the following table configuration:

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = TableEnvironmentLoader.getExecutionEnvironment();
BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironmentLoader.getBatchTableEnvironment();

Table subscribers = tableEnv.fromDataset(subscribers, "firstName, lastName, age");

tableEnv.registerTable("subscribers", subscribers);
```

Now let's assume at a later point i have an additional dataset or tuple3 that contains the same fields; firstName, lastName, age. How can i add that to the existing flink subscribers table? Will using a dynamic table or another way of registering the table (for example:  tableEnv.registerTemporaryView("subscribers", subscribers))  solve the issue? I am not able to add another record to this table without dropping it and creating it again and that is too costly.

please share answer in java.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to use a [dynamic table](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/dynamic_tables.html) in a `StreamTableEnvironment`. The whole point of a dynamic table is that it can be continuously updated.

For a solid intro to Flink SQL, I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnCkwIp_614.